# Convert dataframe to tuple to support CoGroupByKey

Tags: json, python-3.x, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a DataFrame with 3 columns. I want to convert this DataFrame to a python tuple cause CoGroupByKey only accept this type. I want the elements of first column be keys and the elements of other columns in same row be values. And can sink it to BigQuery cause BigQuery only accept json format schema

| peakid | bcdate | smtdate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| TKRG | 3/6/10 | 3/12/10 |
| AMPG | 4/5/10 |  |
| AMAD | 9/5/10 | 4/21/10 |

And I expect result like this:

```
[('TKRG', 
    {'bcdate': ['3/6/10'],
     'smtdate': ['3/12/10']}),
 ('AMPG', 
    {'bcdate': ['4/5/10'],
     'smtdate': []}),
 ('AMAD', 
    {'bcdate': ['9/5/10'],
     'smtdate': ['4/21/10']})
]
```

Reference: https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#cogroupbykey

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Dataframe, you mean a pandas dataframe or a beam dataframe?

In case of beam dataframe, you can use `to_pcollection`  to transform the dataframe to a pcollection and then use the following Map function:

```
  beam.Map(lambda e: (e['peakid'], {'bcdate': [e['bcdate']], 'smtdate':[e['smtdate']]}))
```

In case of your input is a Pandas dataframe, you can transform its records into a dictionary, and pass it to `beam.Create(your_dict)` and then process it with the same Map function

**UPDATE:**

You can read directly the CSV using `beam.io.ReadFromText`. This is an approach that you can use:

```
pipeline | 'Read input file' >> beam.io.ReadFromText(self.csv_path, skip_header_lines=1)
         | 'Parse file' >> beam.Map(parse_file))
```

- `parse_file` is a function that you should write to parse the CSV content. each element would look like this: `value1,value2,value3,etc`, and you can split them and append them to you dictionary
- `skip_header_lines` will help you to skip the header which in your case contains the column name

Else, you can read directly your CSV into a beam dataframe using [read_csv()](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.33.0/apache_beam.dataframe.io.html) and then transform it into a pcollection using `to_pcollection`

In case of multiple columns, the lambda function mentioned in the solution can be replaced with a function. For example:

```
def process_my_elements(element):
    key = element['key']
    values = {}
    for k,v in element.items():
        # pick the values you want to append
    return (key, values)

beam.Map(process_my_elements)
```

Comment: My input is csv file and I transformed it to pandas dataframe, because I'm familiar with it. So now, I need to transform pandas dataframe to dictionary then apply ```  beam.Map(lambda e: (e['peakid'], {'bcdate': [e['bcdate']], 'smtdate':[e['smtdate']]}))
```, right ?

Comment: No you dont' need to transform it to a pandas dataframe. Read your CSV directly with `beam.io.ReadFromText(path_to_csv)` which it will hold it into a pcollection and then you can process it with the Map function.

Comment: Using `p | beam.dataframe.io.read_csv(...)` has the advantage of handling the parsing of lines into rows (including subtleties of quotes and headers). You can pass `splittable=True` if there are no newline-spanning records. As mentioned, you can turn this into an ordinary PCollection with `to_pcollection`and then map it into the required format from there.

Comment: I tried to use **beam.io.ReadFromText(path_to_csv)** and it got error: string indices must be integers. And when I applied **beam.dataframe.io.read_csv(...)**, there is no output. 
Moreover, there are 66 columns in a csv file and I just want to select 3 columns as above. If I processed it like you said, I need to add more than 63 columns in lambda function. Is there any other efficiently way ?

Comment: I added an UPDATE section to my answer, it contains the answers for your questions

Comment: Many thanks for your support. It really works for me before writing to BigQuery.

Comment: However, it still exist an error when writing to BigQuery. If you have free time, please take a look to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73696999/how-to-use-cogroupbykey-sink-to-bigquery-in-apache-beam-using-dataflow